# no warning for missing ctor initializer list?

Tags: c++, valgrind

This code is missing a constructor initializer list:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct s { 
    s() {}  // should be s(): m() {}
    int m;
};

int main() {
    struct s *px = new s();
    if (px->m) {
        printf("true\n");
    } else {
        printf("false\n");
    }
    delete px;
    return 0;
}
```

gcc compiles clean with no warnings:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -O2 test.cpp
```

However, valgrind knows that the class member `m` wasn't initialized:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
==10953== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10953==    at 0x400512: main (test.cpp:10)
==10953==
```

Why didn't gcc warn about the missing initialization (`-Wmissing-field-initializers` or `-Wuninitialized` or `-Wmaybe-uninitialized`)?

Is there a flag I can pass that will catch this case?

Comment: On my team, as a C++ guideline, we've adopted `int m = 0;` in the definition of `s`.  Sidesteps the problem.  I wish C++ required syntax to explicitly make something intentionally uninitialized, like `s() : m(void) {}`.  Alas, that ship has sailed.

Comment: @Eljay I think that's a fabulous idea. `int m = uninitialized;` - which would require a new keyword and break existing code, but... Perhaps `__uninitialized` would be better. It'd not break existing conformant code at least. Porting that older code will be a pain though...

Comment: @TedLyngmo • Kate Gregory [What do we mean when we say nothing at all?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYVxGyido9g) from CppCon 2018, where she laments that in C++ *all the defaults are wrong*.  I concur with her assessment.  (And hence, also, my "Alas, that ship has sailed."  To paraphrase Donald Rumsfeld, "We do not program in C++ with the language we want; we program in C++ with the language we have.")

Comment: @Eljay :-D Indeed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add `-Weffc++` to catch it (inspired by Scott Meyers book "Effective C++"). Strangely enough it does not refer to any other `-W` option (and neither does `clang++`).

The option is however considered, by some, a bit outdated by now, but in this case, it's finding a real problem.

Comment: I wish there was an explicit `-W` flag for just this case instead of bringing in all the other effective c++ stuff.

Comment: @paleozogt I do too. With `-Weffc++` you'll get tons of warnings that are just pointless - in my opinion.

Comment: @paleozogt Sorry, I temporarily added another tool that I thought could be useful, but it turned out it wasn't :-)

Comment: The `-Weffc++` were (arguably) useful for C++98, but are mostly noise for modern C++ (11 and later) since the language itself has improved.  Many of those improvements directly in response to Scott Meyers pointing out the earlier shortcomings.

Comment: Good point @Eljay - it was a book that made life a lot easier in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

GCC also has the `-fanalyzer` flag which does some deeper static analysis than the warning flags do and can catch this specific case on current trunk (but not in GCC 11.2 or earlier):

```
<source>:10:13: warning: use of uninitialized value '*px.s::m' [CWE-457] [-Wanalyzer-use-of-uninitialized-value]
   10 |     if (px->m) {
      |         ~~~~^
  'int main()': events 1-2
    |
    |    9 |     struct s *px = new s();
    |      |                          ^
    |      |                          |
    |      |                          (1) region created on heap here
    |   10 |     if (px->m) {
    |      |         ~~~~~             
    |      |             |
    |      |             (2) use of uninitialized value '*px.s::m' here
    |
```

But I often seem to have problems with the flag for generating false positives. For example in this case it complains about `operator new` potentially returning a null pointer, which cannot ever happen ([bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94355#c8)).

See [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html) for details.

Comment: I just tested it with g++ (GCC) 11.2.1 and it works like a charm! Really nice!